# ( HTML5, JQuery) Attributes of Input elements are ignored by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML5, when I make a text box like below, and press the submit button.

```
<input type='number' name ='search_size' id ='search_size' class="" value="" min="0" max="100" >
```

When the value doesn't meet the min, max value, it will not proceed. However,

My button that handles the text box is made of JQuery. When I type nothing, and click, it processes it.  When I type the value over 100, it also processes it. (There are other values from other tags and etc.)

**Is there something I can add to JQuery so that it will check the condition or requirement in the text box?**

I want to show the JQuery code here, but it is pretty long. Some of it looks like the below.

```
$("#search_submit").off("click").on("click", function(event_receiver){
        $("#loading").css('z-index',-1);
        $("#loading_search").css('top',$("#dialog_data_search").position().top + ($("#dialog_data_search").height()*0.7) );
        $("#loading_search").show();

        var search_data;
        var request_obj = {
                "baseDN" : $("#search_base_dn").val()
                ,"filter":$("#search_filter").val()
                ,"attribute":$("#search_attribute").val()   
                ,"sortAsc":true
                ,"scope":$(":radio[name='search_scope']:checked").val()
                ,"size":$("#search_size").val()};   //<--  this guy!!

        $.ajax({
            url:"/browser/ajaxGetSearchData"
            ,dataType:"json"
            ,data:request_obj
            ,async:true
            ,type:"post"
            ,success:function(return_data){
                if(return_data.success){                        
                    search_data = return_data.result;
                }else{
                    alert(return_data.message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: first of all, in order to use min/max you would need the input to be of type="number"... I don't know if jQuery has anything built in for that, but as far as the spec goes, there is nothing *preventing* you from entering whatever number you want (say, 200), so your code as-is will continue working as it does now even if you change the input type.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation for more information

Comment: @Leroy Stav  oops, you are right, it is type=number. I wrote it here wrong. I didn't put it here but I also added maxlength, required attribute. but didn't work. Jquery just takes whatever input.

Comment: Yes, please reread my comment

Comment: @Leroy Stav  If I change something in Jquery, it won't work?  My question was not doing something in the tag to get it working. I personally think I need to change something in Jquery.

Comment: you can add a validate function in side the jquery click function of yours. in that validate function the value of the input field must be validated. if it exceeds 100 it should return false

Comment: @RAGINROSE  thank you~  that's what I needed. Please put it as an answer. So I can accept it.

Comment: Instead of listening for a click event, which will get emitted even though the form has invalid inputs, the event you want is the `submit` one, which will fire on the `<form>` element.

Comment: @Kaiido  wow, thank you for your tip. It will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a validate function inside the jquery click function of yours. in that validate function the value of the input field must be validated. if it exceeds 100 it should return false

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the <button>'s *click* event, you want to hook on the <form>'s *submit* one.

The *click* event will fire even though the form is invalid, while the *submit* one will first perform the validation:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = e => console.log('btn has been clicked');
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = e => console.log('form has been submitted');
```

```html
<!-- an always invalid form... -->
<form id="form">
  <input name="foo" maxlength="0" required>
  <button id='btn'>bar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use validation bootstrap like this

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name ='search_size' id ='search_size' value="0" min="0" max="100" required>
      </div>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```